# iOS Remote Debugging in Windows

Tags: ios, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I used to be able to hook an iPad up to my PC on USB and launch Firefox WebIDE to debug web development projects on the iPad.

This appears to no longer be working due to an extremely vague notice on Firefox website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence.

How can I debug a website on the iPad using Windows?